# IF statement that returns true if string contains only white space

Tags: c#

I am unsure on how to go about this, i am new to C#. I need to create an IF statement that returns true if a string contains only whitespace.

Another thing i need to figure out how to do is to create an IF statement that returns true if the string matches a day of the week.

IF statements are proving to be a big difficulty for me.

Comment: `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str)`. Use Google dude. If you don't care for `null` strings, thrown in a `str != null` too.

Comment: An empty string is not the same thing as a string with only whitespace, @NickBull.

Comment: @Tim Thasnks for the correction, typed the wrong thing in haste.

Comment: IF statements are proving to be a big difficulty for me. hmmm :)

Comment: @konkked See the next part of that comment

Comment: I'm all for people asking questions, regardless of their experience in programming. But given the nature of the question, I suggest maybe watching a tutorial series on YouTube. Follow along with a guy and you'll learn far more, and far more quickly, than you would asking here when starting out.

Comment: @DrewKennedy Thanks I clicked the wrong tag..lol

Comment: @DrewKennedy - Good suggestion. Even now there's still a lot of things I learn (a lot better) by going through it with a YouTube video. Given the nature of the question, I think it's a simple question of "does the OP understand *logic* altogether" - Programming as a whole is 99% based on logic. If simple logic is hard to understand, then programming just probably isn't the right path to go down. It's not like the concept of the word "if" is confusing. It upsets me that programmers nowadays resort to asking questions on SO, without looking at the *BASICS*, first

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of ways to skin this cat, but here's a sample that illustrates what you can do.

```
void Main()
{
  string day = "monday";
  if (StringIsDayOfWeek(day))
    Console.WriteLine("is day of week");
  else
    Console.WriteLine("is not day of week");

  string s = "";
  if (WhitespaceOnly(s))
    Console.WriteLine("whitespace");
  else
    Console.WriteLine("no whitespace");
}

bool StringIsDayOfWeek (string day)    
{    
  return Enum.GetNames(typeof(DayOfWeek)).Contains(day,     StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
}

bool WhitespaceOnly(string s)
{
  return s!=null && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (myString.Trim().Length==0)
{
    //It was all whitespace.
}
if (
    (myOtherString.ToLower() == "sunday") ||
    (myOtherString.ToLower() == "monday") ||
    (myOtherString.ToLower() == "tuesday") ||
    (myOtherString.ToLower() == "wednesday") ||
    (myOtherString.ToLower() == "thursday") ||
    (myOtherString.ToLower() == "friday") ||
    (myOtherString.ToLower() == "saturday")
   )
{
    //It matched a day of the week.
}
```

Comment: As you probably guessed, this is likely a homework assignment. Please consider this before doing someone's homework for them.

Comment: Could be ... could not be.  *"The first computer program I ever wrote was eight lines long, took me six months to write, and had a bug in it."* It's easy to forget how *baffling* this stuff really is when you're first being introduced to it. (It's been referred-to as "taking a sip from a fire-hose!")

Comment: I am trying my best to learn this stuff, it is not easy for someone that is new at it. The best way i can learn is to try it, then see the correct way to do it so i know where i went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

By the exact wording of your question you need to first make sure it isn't null and then make sure the length is greater than 0 (you said the string only contains whitespace, which means that an empty string doesn't qualify) and then you want to make sure the trimmed length == 0.  The combination of these conditions ensure that:

The string has characters
Trimming whitespace leaves the string with no characters
Therefore the string contains whitespace and only whitespace

```
if (myString != null && myString.Length > 0 && myString.Trim().Length == 0) {
  // You've arrived
}
```

Comment: I suppose your wording is vague.  By "contains only whitespace" you could mean that "if it contains something, that something is only whitespace".  If that is the case in your case, you would have to drop the second condition because empty strings would not get you into the if-body.

Answer (score 0):

For whitespace:

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(myString) && String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(myString))
```

For days of week:

```
using System.Linq;
```

...

```
const string[] DaysOfWeek = {"monday", "tuesday", etc...}
```

...

```
if (DaysOfWeek.Any(x => String.Equals(x, myString, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
```